# Having trouble with a series convergence-divergence test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the below series converge or diverge?
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n\ln (n-1)} $$
I have tried the integral test but stuck to either calculate that integral(substitution, integration by parts) or find an upper/below series that converges/diverges.
Sorry for my bad English and Thanks in advanced!

Comment: $\sum \frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ will work more nicely with the integral test and you can compare yours to it.

Comment: Solution for $\sum \frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$: https://socratic.org/questions/using-the-integral-test-how-do-you-show-whether-sum1-n-log-n-p-diverges-or-conve

Comment: Okay thank you guys, seems like I have made the problem much complicated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given series is clearly comparable with the sum
$$\sum_n \frac{1}{n\log{n}},$$
and you can compare this last one with the harmonic series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ by using the Cauchy condensation test, which basically says that a series $\sum_n a_n$ of non-increasing terms $a_n$ will converge if and only if $\sum_n 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges.

Applying this comparison principle to $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log{n}}$, you deduce that the series diverges, as the harmonic series does.